# Pre-filtering data for R Shiny Datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am writing an app that will allow people to look up an account account and allow a user to choose from two options, line by line in a datatable. I'd like to output those selections eventually.

Questions:

1) Since there is a lot of data getting piped into this, I need to be able to filter the data down to just what is relevant to the user. I would like dropdown lists for each column for each unique value. If this is a good approach, how do I do that? Would it be better to filter the data first, then present the table?

2) I need to output the choices made in some way. For now, I'll just export to a CSV or Excel file or something. But, I'm having trouble getting the output to collapse into just the "items" that I need. Right now, the output will always show the total number of records. I suppose I could just filter the output to the cells with values in them...

3) I think I'll need a submit / action button to write the output once the user is done making choices.

Here is some mocked-up code of what I have so far. I'd really appreciate any help!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(datasets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Choices',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
   server = function(input, output, session) {
    m1 <- iris[1:10,]
    name_pre <- "Item "
    name_suf <- seq(1:nrow(m1))
    rownames(m1) <- paste(name_pre, name_suf, sep ="")
    m2 <- matrix(as.character(1:2),nrow = nrow(m1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    colnames(m2) <- c("Option A","Option B")
    rownames(m2) <- paste(name_pre, name_suf, sep ="")
    #Put radio buttons in the columns
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) {
      m2[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        rownames(m2)[i], m2[i, ]
      )
    }
    m <- cbind(m1,m2)
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE,filter="top", selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup'); 
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(rownames(m), function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
    }
)
```